# What is the date format of e.g. 2020-06-26T21:04:18.1823633Z called?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601

I’m using C# 4.6 to pass a datetime to a webservice that’s expecting it in a format like this: `2020-06-26T21:04:18.1823633Z`, or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ`.

On [this website](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) I’m finding formats that are similar (`SortableDateTimePattern` doesn’t have the `Z` and `UniversalSortableDateTimePat­tern` doesn’t have the `T`), but not identical. Is this a standard datetime format in C# and if not what would be the cleanest way to generate it?

Comment: Looks like ISO-8601 to me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 - .NET can handle this, you can specify the format explicitly when `ToString`ing the date if you always need this exact format. Check out date formatting info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: `string result = MyDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'ffffff'Z'");`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko your format string works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the standard **ISO-8601** format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Most languages/libraries should be able to handle it as is, if not you may need to pluck the `T` or `Z` before processing.

You can format your date with:

```
MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz");
//This will give you the time zone as say... -0400
//2018-06-27T10:08:03.123456-0400
//If you want it as Z (zulu) you can try
MyDate.ToString("o");
//2018-06-27T10:08:03.123456Z
```

You can see all the [formatting options here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)